# Generate random numbers and pass to method in Groovy

Tags: random, groovy

I have `select(int a, int b, int c)` method and I want to pass it 3 random generated values and `select()`. So I do:

```
public void select() {
        Random random = new Random()
        def values= []
        (1..3).each {
            values<< random.nextInt(100 + 1)
        }
        select(values[0], values[1], values[2])
    }
```

But it is Groovy code and I want to make it shorter. How can I do that can I do something like(I can't but how to modify it to run):

```
public void select() {
              select((1..3).each {
            values<< random.nextInt(100 + 1)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def select() {
    select(*new Random().with { r -> (1..3).collect { r.nextInt() } })
}
```

Or, if you don't like the `with`, and want it a bit more explanatory:

```
def select() {
    def r = new Random()
    def args = (1..3).collect { r.nextInt() }
    select(*args)
}
```

Comment: I knew it. Groovy can do it shorter. Thanks @tim_yates. But what * means in front of args in select(*args)?

Comment: @Xelian that's the [spread operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spreading_method_arguments)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8 you can use the Random.ints() method that yields an infinite stream, and peek the first three with limit(3):

```
def select() {
    select(*new Random().ints().limit(3).toArray())
}
```

again with the splat operator to flatten the array